# GetOption() missing – How to fetch value of SetOption dbMaxLocksPerFile of DAO.DBEngine?

Tags: ms-access, dao

[DBEngine.SetOption method (DAO)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/dbengine-setoption-method-dao) temporarily overrides certain internal settings of Microsoft Access database engine – until the instance of MS Access is closed. Its typical use is increasing of **dbMaxLocksPerFile** value:

```
DAO.DBEngine.SetOption dbMaxLocksPerFile, 15000
```

**Is there a way to read the value set using `SetOption`?** (`15000` from the example above)

I found that:

- `GetOption()` counterpart is not offered.
- `Properties` collection does not contain entry for **dbMaxLocksPerFile** setting.

Comment: Review https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/programming/computer-resources/how-to-read-a-value-from-a-registry-key

Comment: @June7 – would you please make the SO a better place by taking time to understand a question before casting votes (close votes)? I am speaking about fetching *temporary* value (set additionally by the code) instead of that default value read from the Registry on DAO engine startup.

Comment: I did understand question and did search for that info. There is a GetOption command in VBA but it did not seem to be able to read that setting. What I referenced seemed to come closest. Here is another discussion https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/threads/how-to-display-maxlocksperfile.202561/

Comment: @June7 - OK that is what I already knew before. So I added an answer explicitly stating this... until someone adds a better answer?

Comment: Can mark your answer accepted, after a brief waiting period, I think.

Comment: @June7 – done, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This value is not readable by any known means.**

What is the closest is to *track all changes to this value manually*. Then we know the last value we set (or initially, we use the DAO Engine startup value, which can be read from the Registry).

**Implementation:**
On startup, read and remember the value from the Registry (DAO Engine does the same, from Registry location which is commonly found documented) and during the runtime, just encapsulate the call of `SetOption()` to procedure/method `SetOption_Locks(newValue)` which takes note of a new value after making call to original `SetOption()`. Create new method `GetOption_Locks()` which returns the value learned before.